# How to get Row & Col index of a select cell in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview wherein I added few textboxes dynamically as shown in the code below:

```
protected void getDateControls()
{
    foreach (GridViewRow grow in gdView.Rows)
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtFrom = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
        txtFrom.ID = "txtFrom";
        txtFrom.Width = 70;
        txtFrom.AutoPostBack = true;
        txtFrom.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtFrom_Changed);
        grow.Cells[5].Controls.Add(txtFrom);

        System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtTo = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
        txtTo.ID = "txtTo";
        txtTo.Width = 70;
        txtTo.AutoPostBack = true;
        txtTo.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtTo_Changed);
        grow.Cells[6].Controls.Add(txtTo);
    }
}
```

I also have jquery function which triggers the datepicker when these textboxes gets focus as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("focus", "input[id*='txtFrom']", function() {
        $(this).datepicker({
            //appendText:'mm/dd/yyyy',
            //showOn: 'both',
            //buttonText: '..',
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            //numberOfMonths:2,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            minDate: new Date(2017, 4, 1),
            maxDate: new Date(2025, 3, 31)
        });
    });
        $(document).on("focus", "input[id*='txtTo']", function() { $(this).datepicker({
            //appendText:'mm/dd/yyyy',
            //showOn: 'both',
            //buttonText: '..',
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            //numberOfMonths:2,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            minDate: new Date(2017, 4, 1),
            maxDate: new Date(2025, 3, 31) 
            });
    });
});
```

Now I want to get the row & col index of that cell where the textbox has focus. How to do that? Please help.

Thanking you all in anticipation.

Comment: The easiest way is to add a property to the TextBox that you can read with jquery.

Comment: Not Clear. Request you to kindly help with some code.

Comment: `txtFrom.Attributes.Add("key", "value");`. Then you can get the values with jquery clientside.